# How to load a package

Tags: packages

I have a package:

```
BeginPackage["HNotation`"];

soma::usage = "asdfa";

Begin["`Private`"];

soma[x_] := x + 1;

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

I save the file with ".m" extension.
So, in another file I tried to load the package:

```
In[2]:= Get["MPA_HNotation.m", Path -> {"/home/mateus/Desktop/"}]

In[3]:= soma[x]

Out[3]= soma[x]
```

It seems that doesn't get the package. What can be wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me, maybe there are old definitions of `soma` that interfere. `Get` would issue a message if it didn't find the file. What if you restart the kernel. What does `?soma` say?

Comment: Did you remember to make all the cells you want evaluated when your package loads the Initialization Cell property?

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. I didn't understand @m_goldberg.

Comment: @Mateus how did you create .m file? What is the raw content of the file?

Comment: First I created a notebook and then I saved as a .m file. I think I got it. The error was when every time I saved as a .m file, all the content becomes a commentary `(* *)`.
So, a question. Every time that I modify my notebook and save as a .m file I will have to uncomment?

Comment: No, you need to have Code cells. If you create a new .wl file it will have them by default. See linked topic and let me know if you disagree with closing.

Comment: Thanks @Kuba. The linked topic solved the problem.